# Why isn't my form submitting correctly in Mozilla, but it works in IE7?

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a report card system. I create a form where we can add the class name, session year and the number of the section and its name. For the session we have used javascript datepicker. For adding the name of the section I am using ajax.

My controller class is addclasses_controller.php

```
<?php
    class AddclassesController extends AppController
    {
        var $name='Addclasses';
        var $helpers = array('Html', 'Javascript', 'Ajax');
        var $components = array('Auth', 'RequestHandler');
        var $uses=array('Addclass','User');


        function add()
        {
            $this->layout = 'internal';
            debug($this->data);
        }


        function addsection()
        {
            $noofsection=$this->data['Addclass']['section'];
            $this->set('noofsection',$noofsection);
        }

    }
?>
```

and the model class name is `addclass.php`

and in the the view section, the `add.ctp`

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Add Class
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
  </tr>
<?php echo $form->create('Addclass', array('url' => array('controller' => 'addclasses', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Class Name</td>
     <td></td>
     <td><?php echo $form->text('classname',array('class' => 'users')); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Session Calender</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="data[Addclass][sdate]" id="AddclassSdate" size="13" datepicker="true" datepicker_format="DD/MM/YYYY"  value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="data[Addclass][edate]" id="AddclassEdate" size="13" datepicker="true" datepicker_format="DD/MM/YYYY"  value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>The Number of Section which you want to add</td>
     <td></td>
     <td><?php echo $form->text('section',array('class' =>'users')); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php echo $ajax->observeField( 'AddclassSection',array('url' => array('controller'=>'addclasses', 'action' =>'addsection'),'frequency' => 0.2,'onChange'=>true,'update'=>'employers'));?>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3"><div id="employers"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3" ><?php echo $form->end('Submit');?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the `addsection.ctp`

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%" align="center">
<?php 
   for($i=1; $i<=$noofsection; $i++) {
      $section="AddclassSec".$i;
      $arr="sec".$i;
      $section_name ="data[Addclass][$arr]";
?>
   <tr>
      <td>Section-<?php echo $i?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="<?php echo $section ?>" value="" class="users" name="<?php echo $section_name ?>"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>    
</table>
```

when I the submit the data, check it and then print the data in Mozilla, I don't find session calender data or the name of the section. But in IE7 it is working properly. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In add.ctp move the $form->create call to before the open table tag and the $form->end call to after the close table tag.  The combination of Firefox, Ajax, and form content within tables is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you could try simplifying your form a little bit. I haven't check but there's a lot of table HTML in your form, which could be breaking it so it doesn't get submitted. That's the only thing I can think of at the moment.